# Setting the Time in a TextClock

Tags: java, android

I want use TextClock in my Android application which display user history. Currently I was using TextView for display time but for better support TimeZone and Hour Format, I am thinking to use TextClock.

I have implemented it like below in XML

```
 <TextClock
                    android:id="@+id/txt_start_time"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.25"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_calendar_small"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                    android:format12Hour="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"
                    android:format24Hour="dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm"
                    android:timeZone="Asia/Calcutta"
                    android:text="15 jul, 2018 10:12:11"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_90"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

But I am not able to set My Time Which I am getting From Server. I was setting it in TextView like below

```
holder.txtStartTime.setText(AppUtils.getSimpleStringDate(mData.get(pPosition).getStartTime(),
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss","dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss") );
```

Instead Now I want use TextClock. How can I set time in TextClock ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use TextClock to set different time and show.

> TextClock can display the current date and/or time as a formatted
>   string.

you can check [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock).

You'll have to use TextView only.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just do this one below:

```
<TextClock
android:id="@+id/clocks"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:format24Hour="'Today is'EEEE"
```

But if you want the "programmatically" version, here it is:

```
buttons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View _view) {
        clocks.setFormat24Hour("'It''s also' yyyy");
    }
});
```

You can change `android:format24Hour` with `android:format12Hour`, yet!

**Result:**
"Today is Thursday" *and tomorrow* "Today is Friday"

**Key: Wrap your custom text with `'` if you want to combine text and date/time.**

Comment: but this will just set time format but you cannot set a specific time into textclock